# perl : DBD::Sybase : what is max number of queries that can be run in one dbh->execute

Tags: perl, sybase, dbi

I know that DBD::Sybase can handle multi-statement SQL commands in a single execute. Is there any limit of number of queries that   DBD::Sybase can handle.

I have  a file containing 'X' number of query. Size of file or number of queries are not known. Those are generated by other program and there are N number of such files.

my program read those files and execute using dbh->execute(); 
while most of case that works fine but few cases are there where dbh->execute() fails and core dump occurred. I found that those file, for which dbh->execute() failed are huge. approx 20K lines.

I am using Sybase version 15.7.

Thanks in Advance,
Dhawal